# Custom Access and authorization in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

How can I configure sharepoint 2010 application for custom access and authorization control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by User Permissions on the document library or list. By default it inherits permission from parent site but we can configure it by using stop inheriting permission in list/library settings.